# GeoPandas dataframe from PostGIS table having date column

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql, geopandas, datetime

I have this PostgreSQL PostGIS database

[image: PostGIS database]

and I want to read this data in GeoPandas.

I am able to create the GeoPandas database when I exclude the columns having dates/datetime

```
#Reading data from postgis in geopandas 

conne = psycopg2.connect(user='postgres', password='your_password', host='localhost', port= '5432', database="agro_dss")

print ("connection to the database suscessfull")

#all columns except date columns 


sql = "select geometry, state_name, district_name, rainfall, temperature_max, temperature_min, humidity, humidity2, wind_speed, wind_direction, cloud_cover from forecast_data"


pstgis_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis(sql, conne, geom_col='geometry')

pstgis_df
```

I have followed the steps as in [GeoPandas documentation](https://geopandas.org/reference.html?highlight=from_postgis#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis)

but it is showing error

```
conne = psycopg2.connect(user='postgres', password='your_password', host='localhost', port= '5432', database="agro_dss")

print ("connection to the database suscessfull")

sql_base = "select geometry, rainfall from forecast_data"

pstgis_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis(sql, conne, geom_col='geometry' , parse_dates={'Issue_date': '%Y-%m-%d'})
```

what would be the proper syntax for adding the columns having date in postgis table to GeoPandas dataframe?

when I am passing date column in the SQL query, its showing error. How to add that column?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but how to fix " parse_dates={Issue_date: '%Y-%m-%d'})  " here in : pstgis_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis(sql, conne, geom_col='geometry' , parse_dates={Issue_date: '%Y-%m-%d'}) @BERA

Comment: I don't know how to do that, i just pasted the code from my jupyter notebook, and it was showing like its showing now,  that's why i have posted the snaps for reference. @BERA

Comment: tried that here already https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBNcy.png @BERA

Comment: sorry @BERA , forgot to put the column name in inverted-commas. Thanks, it parsed the date column, but by doing so, it is parsing the date but not showing that column in dataframe. For doing so I added the column name in sql query, and when i am doing so, it’s showing error https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqfiQ.png, even after correcting the suggestions https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f0ko.png

Comment: Please don't post pictures of error messages/code but the actual text.

Comment: Do note that you have written your password in the code pictures... you may want to change it

Comment: It's on local host for now, but i will keep that in mind. And i am not sure, how to post the code in proper manner, Like when I paste the code here from my jupyter notebook, it appears distorted with a regular text as in MS-Word, doesn't appers like a code, which make me post the pictures too. @JGH

Comment: You can select the text and click the `{}` icon to format it as code, or you can manually add 3 backticks (```) on its own line before and after the code section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres is case sensitive. The error message tells you that `issue_date` is not found, and goes as far as suggesting that you may be meaning `Issue_date`, with a capital `I`.

To reference an uppercase column name, it must be within double quotes

`select "Issue_date" from myTable`

You would have to escape it within the query string

```
sql_base = "select geometry, rainfall,\"Issue_date\" from forecast_data"
```

Comment: thanks a lot @JGH, it resolved the problem.

Comment: Since I am new to stackoverflow, I am not yet acquainted with the options available here. I tried to vote as this answer is useful but it showed in the popup : Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. @JGH, thanks for your time though.

Comment: :-) don't worry, this aspect is indeed a bit unclear: only the user that asked a question can "accept" the answer. Anybody - including the user that asked the question -  that find the answer useful can "upvote" it (or "downvote" it!), provided they have at least 15 points of reputation